# Check a List With If Statement in a Loop Using Python/Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have an `Article` model which I fetch from when a user successfully logs in:

```
articles = Article.objects.all()
```

I also have `Likes` model which has `user_id` and `article_id` to record articles users have liked.

```
articles_liked = Likes.objects.values_list('article_id', flat = True)
users_who_liked = Likes.objects.values_list('user_id', flat = True)
```

The `article_id` gives a list of article users have liked while `users_who_liked` gives a list of users who liked those articles as shown below:

```
articles_liked = [4, 3, 5, 6, 10]
users_who_liked = [1, 13, 15, 16, 110]
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to tell if a particular post is already liked by the logged in user in my template.

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <p>{{article.content}}</p>
        {% if this_user_id in users_who_liked and article.id in articles_liked %}
            <p class = 'likes'> 2 </p>
        {% else %}
            <p class = 'likes already_liked'> 2 </p>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Let's assume `this_user_id = 1` and the articles he/she likes is `4`, the `if` statement returns `True` for all the articles and the `else` block never get to be executed.

How can I do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables `articles_liked` and `users_who_liked` are not correlated to each other. They always contain *all* liked articles and *all* users who liked, but between them there is no relation in your template context which you can rely on.

Therefore your `if` statement will always return `True` for every user who liked *any* article which has been liked by *at least one* user.

Assuming from your question that `Like` has a foreign key ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships)) to `User` and a foreign key to `Article` you could just add a filter to your `articles_liked` assignment to only retrieve likes from the current user:

```
articles_liked = Likes.objects.filter(user_id=this_user_id).values_list('article_id', flat = True)
```

Then in your template you can simply check if the current article is in this list:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <p>{{article.content}}</p>

    {% if article.id in articles_liked %}
        <p class = 'likes'> 2 </p>
    {% else %}
        <p class = 'likes already_liked'> 2 </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your Likes object has a reference to both Users and Articles, why not exploit this in your view? That way you control the logic in your view and template just becomes a simple if statement:

```
def some_view(request):
   articles = Article.objects.all()
   user = request.user
   article_list = []
   for a in articles:
     # Create a tuple, with a flag if the user has liked this article or not.
     article_status = (Likes.objects.filter(article_id=a.pk, user_id=user.pk).exists(), a,)
     article_list.append(article_status)
   return render(request, 'template.html', {'articles': article_list})
```

Now, in your template you have the following:

```
{% for liked,article in articles %}
  {% if liked %}
      <strong>You already liked this article!</strong>
  {% endif %}
  {{ article }}
{% endfor %}
```